# How to Vue splice method to remove the product name?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to try remove the product name.When i click the `+`, push method to add the product name of Xiaomi.Then when click the `-`, But the result is `remove： ["Iphone 4S"]`.I think it should console log is `remove： ["Xiaomi"]`.Go to the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhouyulong/8ocwtyL0/).

#### Look at the gif:

[image]

#### Look at the picture:

[image]

#### Look the javascript file:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    phone: [{
      id: "1",
      name: 'Iphone 4S',
      price: '300',
      count: "0"
    }, {
      id: "2",
      name: 'Xiaomi',
      price: '200',
      count: "0"
    }, {
      id: "3",
      name: 'vivo X20',
      price: '320',
      count: "0"
    }],
    addcart: []
  },
  methods: {
    lessClick(item) {
        if (item.count > 0) {
          item.count--
            console.log("remove：", this.addcart.splice(item.name, 1))

        }
      },
      addClick(item) {
        item.count++
          console.log("add：", this.addcart.push(item.name))

      }
  }
})
```

#### HTML file:

```html
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item,index) in phone">
      Product name： {{item.name}}
      <br>Product price：{{item.price}}
      <br>
      <a class="a-less" @click="lessClick(item)">-</a>
      <input type="text" v-model="item.count">
      <a class="a-add" @click="addClick(item)">+</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method wrong. It takes index of the item to remove as the first argument. So you first need to find the index by item name, maybe using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method. It should be something like this:

```javascript
lessClick(item) {
  if (item.count > 0) {
    item.count--
    const index = this.addcart.indexOf(item.name)

    if (index > -1) {
      const removedName = this.addcart.splice(index, 1)
      console.log("remove：", removedName)
    }
  }
},
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/8ocwtyL0/7/